# Symfony2 can't catch ResourceNotFoundException

Tags: php, symfony, exception, routes

I created a service which converts uris to routenames with parameters
I'm trying to catch the ResourceNotFoundException for not existing uris but getting 500 Error and exception

```
<?php

namespace OOOO\AdvertisingBundle\Utilities;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class RouteConverter
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function uriToRoute($uri)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->match($uri);
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return null;
        }
        $result['name'] = $matched['_route'];
        unset($matched['_route']);
        unset($matched['_controller']);
        $result['parameters'] = $matched;

        return $result;
    }

    public function generateRoute($name, $parameters)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH);
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            return null;
        }
        return $matched;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you show your php log ? you not use Exception, so you should catch(\Exception $e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace `Exception` by `ResourceNotFoundException`. And don't forget `use` statement:

```
<?php

namespace OOOO\AdvertisingBundle\Utilities;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;

class RouteConverter
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function uriToRoute($uri)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->match($uri);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {

            return null;
        }
        $result['name'] = $matched['_route'];
        unset($matched['_route']);
        unset($matched['_controller']);
        $result['parameters'] = $matched;

        return $result;
    }

    public function generateRoute($name, $parameters)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH);
        } catch (ResourceNotFoundException $e) {

            return null;
        }
        return $matched;
    }
}
```

or if you want to use `Exception`, don't forget slash before name in Symfony:

```
<?php

namespace OOOO\AdvertisingBundle\Utilities;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;

class RouteConverter
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function uriToRoute($uri)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->match($uri);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return null;
        }
        $result['name'] = $matched['_route'];
        unset($matched['_route']);
        unset($matched['_controller']);
        $result['parameters'] = $matched;

        return $result;
    }

    public function generateRoute($name, $parameters)
    {
        try {
            $matched = $this->router->generate($name, $parameters, UrlGeneratorInterface::RELATIVE_PATH);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {

            return null;
        }
        return $matched;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception is generic, it catch all exceptions

Comment: @ziollek Only in case if `ResourceNotFoundException` **extends** `Exception`

Comment: all exception MUST be an instance of the Exception class or a subclass of Exception. Pls read manual: http://pl1.php.net/exceptions